# a mod can review his own flag?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a doubt that If we flag a moderator's or user's (who got privileged to access Mod-Tools( > 10,100 Rep) ) post/question or anything , will he able to  review them ?

Comment: Are you worried about what he will do in that case?

Comment: New doubt...seth your mind working like Edison  :P

Comment: We trust those users, hence why they have access to the tools, if they're not trustworthy or abuse this power we'll take away access. We tend to trust those who have earned it/are elected rather than not

Answer (score 5):

A moderator can indeed review a post of theirs that was flagged.

However, for most flags (duplicates), its cut and dry and the moderator will vote to close the question.

For those flags that aren't cut and dry, they generally let someone else take care of it, or they bring it up in the moderator-only chat.